# writev operation example here it is not printing integer value in the stdout

Tags: c, linux

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd;
    fd=open(argv[1],O_RDWR|O_APPEND);
    printf("fd=%d\n",fd);
    char *str0 = "hello ";
    char *str1 = "world ";
    int x=5;
    //char ch = 'a';
    struct iovec iov[3];
    ssize_t nwritten;

    iov[0].iov_base = str0;
    iov[0].iov_len = strlen(str0);
    iov[1].iov_base = str1;
    iov[1].iov_len = strlen(str1);
    iov[2].iov_base = (&x);
    iov[2].iov_len = sizeof(x);

    nwritten = writev(1, iov, 3);//1 for stdout

    printf("\n number written=%d\n",nwritten);
}
```

Here it is not printing integer value in the stdout.
please anyone suggest some solution for me.

My actual output is

```
hello world
```

I want

```
hello world 5
```

Comment: What output are you seeing on stdout ? Try `fflush(stdout)` at the end of main.

Comment: I excecuted your code online(http://ideone.com/jKPFyq) and got the correct output.

Comment: Side note: `printf("\n number written=%zd\n",nwritten);`

Comment: @Nishant It isn't correct. OP wants `5` printed after `hello world` output.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem belongs to the `ASCII` format you want to see into `stdout`. 
You are writing to the `stdout` the value of `x` that is `5` that it isn't a printable char in `ASCII`.

If you test your code using `x=0x31` you will see: `hello world 1` because of `0x31` is the ASCII value of `'1'`

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd;
    fd=open(argv[1],O_RDWR|O_APPEND);
    printf("fd=%d\n",fd);
    char *str0 = "hello ";
    char *str1 = "world ";
    int x=0x31;
    //char ch = 'a';
    struct iovec iov[3];
    ssize_t nwritten;

    iov[0].iov_base = str0;
    iov[0].iov_len = strlen(str0);
    iov[1].iov_base = str1;
    iov[1].iov_len = strlen(str1);
    iov[2].iov_base = (&x);
    iov[2].iov_len = sizeof(x);

    nwritten = writev(1, iov, 3);//1 for stdout

    printf("\n number written=%zd\n",nwritten);
}
```

OUTPUT

```
hello world 1
 number written=16
```

As you can see I also changed the format specifier for `nwritten` variable. `ssize_t` type wants `%zd` as format specifier.

Another way to do that is to convert the integer value to `ASCII` using [snprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd;
    fd=open(argv[1],O_RDWR|O_APPEND);
    printf("fd=%d\n",fd);
    char *str0 = "hello ";
    char *str1 = "world ";

    int x=5;
    char intStr[2];
    snprintf(intStr, sizeof(intStr), "%d", x);


    //char ch = 'a';
    struct iovec iov[3];
    ssize_t nwritten;

    iov[0].iov_base = str0;
    iov[0].iov_len = strlen(str0);
    iov[1].iov_base = str1;
    iov[1].iov_len = strlen(str1);
    iov[2].iov_base = intStr;
    iov[2].iov_len = strlen(intStr);

    nwritten = writev(1, iov, 3);//1 for stdout

    printf("\n number written=%zd\n",nwritten);
}
```

OUTPUT

```
hello world 5
 number written=16
```

Comment: @debi You're welcome. Close the question as answered.